# The double click to open folders or files not working

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

I have used Ubuntu 12.04 and it works well till i did some updates. after updating and installing some packages, the double click for open files or folders didn't work, but works well for other things like maximize or minimize. i think the problem occurred after installing tweak application. now i upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.1 and still have the problem.